# composer update не создает папку .git

Tags: php, git, github, phpstorm, composer

Есть проект, который есть в репе git`а, внутри есть composer.json, по которому подтягиваются доп. репы. Суть проблемы такова, когда я хочу править репы из одного окна в phpstorm, я иду в настройки version control и добавляю папку с клонированным репозиторием. Но это не работает с репами, которые загрузились через composer update. Все из-за того, что шторм не находит папку .git в корне клонированного проекта. Вопрос - какие настройки могут помочь для этого или как исправить это (потому что незадолго до этого все работало как надо и я ничего криминального со штормом не делал)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981292/how-to-make-composer-not-create-a-git-directory-for-a-package

Comment: Тут немного другое, мне надо, чтобы клонирование шло с папкой .git

Comment: Попробуйте делать апдейт зависимых пакетов так: `composer update --prefer-source package-name`